# Conditional column rendering

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm working with jsf 2.0. I have this datatable

```
<h:dataTable value="#{agreement.licenseProducts}"
    var="licenseProduct"
    styleClass="pnx-table pnx-table-bdr pnx-table-unstyled mp-license-info">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Product" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{licenseProduct.description}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Serial Number" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{licenseProduct.serialNumber}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{agreement.labelForConcurrency}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{licenseProduct.concurrent}" />
    </h:column>
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{agreement.managementTool != 'NONE'}">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{agreement.labelForLicenseType}" />
                <span class="pnx-icon-right pnx-icon-info pnx-tooltip">
                    <div class="pnx-tooltip-content">
                        <h:outputText value="Tooltip content" />
                    </div>
                </span>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{licenseProduct.licenseBase}" />
        </h:column>
    </ui:fragment>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{agreement.labelForSeatCount}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{licenseProduct.seats}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The problem is that the ui:fragment part is not working. No matter what the attribute's value is, it will NEVER show the column.

Any ideas?

--EDIT--

Just in case, I have other ui:fragments that depend on that same attribute, and they do render correctly depending on the attribute's value. I'm sure it has to do with the dataTable and the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rendered`'s attribute of `<h:column>` tag performs simply the job :

```
<h:column rendered="#{agreement.managementTool != 'NONE'}">
       ...        
</h:column>
```