# JSF tomahawk t:columns conditional rendering

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, conditional-statements, tomahawk

So, umm, I've got JSF tomahawk table

```
<t:dataTable ... >
    <t:columns ...>
          ... content to render ...
    </t:columns>
</t:dataTable>
```

and I want to omit some columns. I can't change data model. Columns total count varies from time to time.

Tried

```
<t:dataTable ... >
    <t:columns ...>
         <c:if  test="#{condition}">
                ... content to render ...
         </c:if>
    </t:columns>
</t:dataTable>
```

but it still outputs empty columns.

This answer is not an option:
[Conditional column rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906484/conditional-column-rendering)

because I use `t:columns` and not `t:column`.

How can I omit certain columns when I'm using `t:columns`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add display:none; to the header and row styles if the condition is met (omitting by the header name in this case). The selected column disappears.

```
<t:dataTable ... >
    <t:columns var="colH" value="#{dataModel.colHeaders}"  headerstyle="#{colH eq 'frodo'? 'display:none;' : ''}" style="#{colH eq 'frodo'? 'display:none;' : ''}">
          ... content to render ...
    </t:columns>
</t:dataTable>
```